# capture group and the i in regex. What is it?

Tags: regex

I don't understand this part of a long regex:

```
(?i)(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)(?-i)\z/
```

What are the parenthesis for again? Is it a capture group? What is the i flag in the capture group for?

I think the only parts I understand are the | and the \z at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby

> (?i) - start case sensitive mode
>
> (jpg|jpeg|gif|png) - Capturing group to select from any of them (Case
>   insensitive)
>
> (?-i) - end case sensitive mode (only the part between (?i) and (?-i) is case insensitive)

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?i) #Start of case insensitive mode (Whatever follows will be matched irrespective of being lower case or upper case)
  (  #Capturing group
    jpg|
    jpeg|  #Select any one of them
    gif|
    png
  )  #End of capturing group
(?-i) #End of case insensitive mode
\z  #Can match after line break
```